# ORDER BY and GROUP BY of MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have two mySQL tables as follows:

```
[product] table
P_id | Name | Quantity
1    | B    | 10
2    | C    | 15
3    | A    | 8

[attribute] table 
P_id | Name  | Quantity
1    | Black | 5
1    | Red   | 5
2    | Blue  | 6
2    | Black | 9
```

How can I write an SQL query so that it can show the result from the above two tables as follows:
Report:

```
P_id | Name  | Quantity
3    | A     | 8
1    | B     | 10
1    | Black | 5
1    | Red   | 5
2    | C     | 15
2    | Black | 9
2    | Blue  | 6
```

These should be sorted on [Name] column, but these should be grouping on P_id column as above. By "grouping" on P_id, I mean "keeping all records with the same P_id next to each other". IS it possible to retrieve as above arrangement using a single SQL query.

Comment: To clarify, by "grouping" you mean "keeping all records with the same `P_id` next to each other" (instead of an actual `GROUP BY` clause), right?

Comment: What is the relation between those two tables? What do you want to know exactly? My guess is product.P_id is foreign key referenced by attribute.P_id. Is taht right?

Comment: As I understand it, the ordering is by product name for products and by related product name for attributes. At first the model seems weird but it makes kinda sense after a while.

Comment: @Wiseguy: Yes, by "grouping" I mean "keeping all records with the same P_id next to each other"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT P_id, Name, Quantity FROM (
  SELECT P_id, Name, Quantity, Name as parent, 1 as level
    FROM product
  UNION
  SELECT a.P_id, a.Name, a.Quantity, p.Name as parent, 2 as level
    FROM attribute a JOIN product p ON a.P_id = p.P_id
) combined ORDER BY parent, level, Name
```

Comment: I believe your answer can solve my problem, but it doesn't show all records of one P_id together. I want to keep all records with the same P_id together.

Comment: +1 for understanding the desired order (and, of course, actually accomplishing it)

Comment: fixed and tested: 1) you need an alias for the subselect in MySQL. 2) Ordering by Name is needed to sort attributes with the same P_id.
Now it gives exactly the results desired.

Answer (score 0):

It should be Union operation, I believe like this:

```
select * from product union select * from attribute order Name;
```

Not sure why you wrote you need `group by' since your output is not grouped by any column.

Comment: I don't see grouping either in the example in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you just need an union of both tables?
You can try this:

```
Select P_id, Name, Quantity
From product

Union

Select P_id, Name, Quantity
From attribute

Order by 2
```

Comment: wasimchy says he wants grouping, but there is no grouping necessary.

Comment: According to your example, no group by is necessary, only an union. The amount of products is already on the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT P_id, Name , Quantity FROM product
   UNION ALL
   SELECT P_id, Name , Quantity FROM attribute
) Order by Name
```

Comment: SELECT * and the () will not be necessary

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use grouping my friend. Then you can order on *Both* of you required columns like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product UNION SELECT * FROM attribute ORDER BY Name, P_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them ordered by P_id and then Name, this should work.

```
(SELECT P_id, Name, Quantity FROM product)
UNION
(SELECT P_id, Name, Quantity FROM attribute)
ORDER BY P_id, Name;
```